# Convention on infinity comparision

Tags: infinity

What's the difference between $-\infty \leq a \leq \infty$ and $-\infty < a < \infty$ conceptually or otherwise.

It doesn't really affect the solution to the solution of this problem I'm working out( I hope) but the solution states $\leq$ and I have $<$ . So I would appreciate an explanation on how are they different.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: We need more context.  I guess you have $-\infty < a < \infty$ in some setting?

Comment: Well, in the problem I was solving, I had to use $-\infty < a < b < \infty$ but the solution stated $-\infty \leq a < b \leq \infty$ . It was in relation to the distribution function of a random variable of a probability function, if that helps. I have seen such differences elsewhere also. Hence , the doubt. Thanks for helping again. :) @GEdgar